# my symfony 2.3 composer file does not match the official release version

Tags: symfony

**EDIT : I confused symfony/framework-standard-edition and symfony/symfony !
I upgraded 2.3 to 2.8 with symfony/framework-standard-edition. It works perfectly. I love symfony.**

I have symfony 2.3 since few year (I regularly update) and I realize that composer.json does not correspond to the official version that evolved.
why ?

my composer.json sf v2.3 :

```
{
    "name" : "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description" : "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "type" : "project",
    "license" : [
        "MIT"
    ],
    "require" : {
        "symfony/symfony" : "2.3.*",
        "coresphere/console-bundle" : "@stable",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm" : ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "@stable",
        "jms/serializer-bundle" : "@stable",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle" : "@stable",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
        "twig/extensions" : "1.0.*",
        "guzzle/guzzle" : "3.9.2",
        "php" : ">=5.3.3",
        "sensio/generator-bundle" : "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "1.2.*",
        "cocur/slugify" : "@stable",
        "dailymotion/sdk": "@stable",
        "simple-html-dom/simple-html-dom": "*",
        "rukbat/bitly-bundle": "@stable",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "@stable",
        "marcw/wurst-bundle": "dev-master",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^1.4"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-0" : {
            "" : "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "vendor/simple-html-dom/simple-html-dom/",
            "vendor_nocomposer/"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability" : "stable",
    "config" : {
        "bin-dir" : "bin"
    },
    "scripts" : {
        "post-update-cmd" : [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd" : [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "extra" : {
        "branch-alias" : {
            "@stable" : "2.3-dev"
        },
        "symfony-web-dir" : "web",
        "symfony-app-dir" : "app",
        "incenteev-parameters" : {
            "file" : "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

2.3 github version :

```
{
    "name": "symfony/symfony",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "The Symfony PHP framework",
    "keywords": ["framework"],
    "homepage": "https://symfony.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Fabien Potencier",
            "email": "fabien@symfony.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Symfony Community",
            "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "doctrine/common": "~2.4",
        "paragonie/random_compat": "~1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "~1.1",
        "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.1",
        "twig/twig": "~1.23|~2.0",
        "psr/log": "~1.0"
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/browser-kit": "self.version",
        "symfony/class-loader": "self.version",
        "symfony/config": "self.version",
        "symfony/console": "self.version",
        "symfony/css-selector": "self.version",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "self.version",
        "symfony/debug": "self.version",
        "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "self.version",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "self.version",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "self.version",
        "symfony/filesystem": "self.version",
        "symfony/finder": "self.version",
        "symfony/form": "self.version",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "self.version",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "self.version",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "self.version",
        "symfony/intl": "self.version",
        "symfony/locale": "self.version",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "self.version",
        "symfony/options-resolver": "self.version",
        "symfony/process": "self.version",
        "symfony/propel1-bridge": "self.version",
        "symfony/property-access": "self.version",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "self.version",
        "symfony/routing": "self.version",
        "symfony/security": "self.version",
        "symfony/security-acl": "self.version",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "self.version",
        "symfony/security-core": "self.version",
        "symfony/security-http": "self.version",
        "symfony/serializer": "self.version",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "self.version",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bridge": "self.version",
        "symfony/templating": "self.version",
        "symfony/translation": "self.version",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "self.version",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "self.version",
        "symfony/validator": "self.version",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "self.version",
        "symfony/yaml": "self.version"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.4,>=2.4.5",
        "monolog/monolog": "~1.3",
        "propel/propel1": "~1.6",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0",
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "~0.3.1|~1.0|~2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "Symfony\\": "src/" },
        "classmap": [
            "src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Resources/stubs",
            "src/Symfony/Component/Intl/Resources/stubs"
        ],
        "files": [ "src/Symfony/Component/Intl/Resources/stubs/functions.php" ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/Tests/"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using 3.1 ?

Comment: I just wanted to upgrade to version 2.8 and the documentation indicates to only change the line symfony/symfony or the new composer.json is very different now compare to my version

Comment: Can you post both?

Comment: I have seen that advice about only changing one line but it seldom ends well for major jumps.  What I do is to install a brand new 2.7 project then use it's composer.json as a starting point, adding in whatever dependencies I happen to use.

Answer (score 1):

`composer.json` only changes when you change it.

`composer.lock` uses latest version compatible with `composer.json` wildcards. read more here [composer versions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md)

so my guess will be that your version is locked to major symfony e.g `"~2.3"`